# python, can't import modules from PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

For a start, I'm new to python. I'm trying to use PyQt4 in making GUI for a database that I'll create later so I'm learning how to construct interface using python language
I installed PyQt4 using .WHL file and it worked. But when I try to use a code like:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Edit: I resolved the issue! 
there was a duplicated PyQt4 in my python folder than I tried to installed before and failed . when I removed that duplicate folder and uninstalled my older python version it worked nicely now

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Please make your edit as an answer and mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue! there was a duplicated PyQt4 in my python folder than I tried to installed before and failed . when I removed that duplicate folder and uninstalled my older python version it worked nicely now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if you installed PyQt4 correctly?  For that you can use simply:

```
import PyQt4
```

and see if it produces an error.

Comment: Already done that. It doesn't produce any error when I import PyQt4 directly

Comment: Ok already resolved the issue. seems I had a duplicated wrong version of PyQt4. Thank you for answering!